# Unity Editor GUI, change the label width of EditorGUILayout.Toggle

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can't find a way to increase the label width of EditorGUILayout.Toggle. Here's my code, it doesn't do anything and Unity clips the text and cuts it short.

```
GUILayoutOption[] options = new GUILayoutOption[] {
GUILayout.Width(400.0f), 
GUILayout.MinWidth(250.0f), 
GUILayout.ExpandWidth(true) 
};
MyBoolValue = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("My Long Description Text Here", MyBoolValue, options);
```

I did try wrapping the Toggle button with

```
 EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
 EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
```

But it also didn't do anything. What can I do remove clipping from the text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth` before doing your `Toggle`, and then restore it to its original value so you don't mess up any subsequent controls.

```
float originalValue = EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth;
EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth = 400;   
MyBoolValue = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("My Long Description Text Here", MyBoolValue);
EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth = originalValue;
```